# Dropdownlist DataSource to Value Object

Tags: c#, asp.net, object, 3-tier, three-tier

My application is built with three-tier architecture. However, I want the dropdownlists to data source to the Value Object class. Currently I am data sourcing the dropdownlists from Data Access Layer -> Business Logic Layer -> Presentation Layer. But I want to datasource the lists from the Value Object. Therefore, what I want is from Data Access Layer -> Value Object -> Business Logic Layer -> Presentation Layer (dropdown). I tried to datasource it to the value object but it gives me the error of "Invalid Data Source; Must be of type IListSource, IEnumerable, or IDataSource". Thanks you!

Here's my code:

ReligionVO

```
public class ReligionVO
{
    private string religionCode;

    public string ReligionCode
    {
        get { return religionCode; }
        set { religionCode = value; }
    }

    private string religion;

    public string Religion
    {
        get { return religion; }
        set { religion = value; }
    }
}
```

ReligionDAO

```
public class ReligionDAO
{
    private DB db = new DB();

    public DataTable SelectAllReligion()
    {
        return db.GetData("SELECT * FROM Religions");
    }
}
```

ReligionBLO

```
public class ReligionBLO
{
    private ReligionVO religionVO = new ReligionVO();
    private ReligionDAO religionDAO = new ReligionDAO();

    public DataTable SelectAllReligion()
    {
        return religionDAO.SelectAllReligion();
    }

    /* this is the code I tried to datasource to the Value Object
    public ReligionVO SelectAllReligion()
    {
        dt = religionDAO.SelectAllReligion();
        foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
        {
            religionVO.ReligionCode = dr["religion_code"].ToString();
            religionVO.Religion = dr["religion"].ToString();
        }
        return religionVO;
    }
    */
}
```

ASPX

```
ddlReligion.DataSource = religionBLO.SelectAllReligion();
ddlReligion.DataValueField = "religion_code";
ddlReligion.DataTextField = "religion";
ddlReligion.DataBind();
```

Here's a screenshot of the error message:
[image: ReligionVO is an invalid data source]

Comment: the commented code is throwing the error?

Comment: the DataSource must be a type implementing IListSource,IDataSource or IEnumerable.
I don't see any error is your un-commented code logic.

Comment: @AmitKumarGhosh the commented codes throws the error. The uncommented code is my current code which works fine, but I want to know if there's a way for the commented code to work.

Answer (score 2):

Your method declaration is correct. The problem is in the actual method implementation. You have specified `DataTable` as the return type in this line :

```
public DataTable SelectAllReligion()
    {
        return religionDAO.SelectAllReligion();
    }
```

And in the actual method implementation(the commented code in your question), you are using this :

```
public ReligionVO SelectAllReligion()
    {
       //your logic
        return religionVO;
    }
```

Just replace `ReligionVO` in the above code with `DataTable` and return the `dt` object instead of `religionVO`. Like this :

```
public DataTable SelectAllReligion()
{
    //your logic
    return dt;
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: The ReligionBLO has a method defined which should suffice

Comment: Thats what I pointed. OP needs to directly return that method result since its of `DataTable` return type.

Comment: @HarveySpecter Thank you for your answer, but isn't your code similar to my code that is top of the commented code in ReligionBLO? The uncommented code is my current code which works correctly. But I want the dropdownlist to data source to the Value Object and not execute the Data Access Object.